# Is there any best way to write some scripts automated in putty?

Tags: unix, putty

I have some daily performed unix scripts like (cd,ls, etc...) to run on a remote server from putty.Basically I need to automate my daily tasks.
Can anyone suggest me which is the best way to write the scripts.

Comment: write a script and put it in a cronjob...

Comment: Explain what you really want to do. A script that only performs `cd` won't help and where do you want the output of `ls` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Plink* it is in the putty collection (http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

For more details see this thread [putty from a batch file and a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21804019/putty-from-a-batch-file-and-a-script)