# How to send putty commands via a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, putty

So what I'm trying to do is use putty.exe from the command line to open a connection to a serial port. I have that part covered, I get in and what I then need to do is send some commands over the port.

I've tried a `-m` and a .txt file with what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't seem to work.

**commands**

```
<cr>
<cr>
M<cr>
4055222<cr>
test<cr>
N<cr>
```

I have this so far that opens the session

```
start "" C:\"Program Files"\PuTTY\putty.exe -load "test"
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Does the file have executable rights?

Comment: Did you put the script file on your remote system?  Did you make sure the script file only uses Line Feeds and not Carriage Return Line Feed?

Answer (score 0):

With Putty the only thing I've found is to use auto-hotkey and write a script to send the commands, with pauses.

I found this after a little more searching:
[putty from a batch file and a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21804019/putty-from-a-batch-file-and-a-script)

p.s.
Have you taken a look at GitBash?
I prefer it over putty when I need to do something other than ssh...

Comment: How is Git Bash related to this question?

Comment: "Any advice would be appreciated!" - I would place it under this. GitBash supports Serial as of some months ago.

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm limited to a Windows environment for this.

Comment: If you don't have much CLI experience I wouldn't recommend Gitbash. But you can create a script with auto-hotkey that sends keystrokes so when you're connected you can hit CTRL-E or something and it will send all of your commands.

Comment: If you still want to use -m, check out the link in my answer.